# Wordpress doesn't allow to upload images larger than 128 KB

Tags: php, wordpress, filesize, upload-max-filesize

WordPress 6.1-358 without additional plugins and themes, newly installed.

PHP 8.11, settings:

`memory_limit = 256M`

`post_max_size = 256M`

`upload_max_filesize = 256M`

`max_execution_time = 180`

`max_input_time = 60`

I can't upload files more than 128 KB to the gallery. Found out empirically.

Error message:
The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels.

I **CAN** upload files even 4000x4000 pixels, but less than 128 KB.

I **CAN NOT** upload files even 500x500 pixels, but more than 128 KB.

Tricks with **add_filter** doesn't help

Comment: have you checked with your hosting server?

Comment: What should i check?

Comment: if theres a cap on file size

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue on my local install. Uploading works if I downgrade back to PHP 7.4. I’m pretty sure PHP 8 used to work, too, so I believe this is something brought by a recent Wordpress update.

Comment: Doesn't work on 7.4 for me.